# Trying to add a preloaded animation and mouse effect on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, animation, mouseevent, preloader

I was looking to add a preloader animation and mouse effect like the site: http://plantweb.wpengine.com/duplicated-eat-food-4966/

Can you see the animation: https://prnt.sc/vvlrii and mouse effect: https://prnt.sc/vvlrx6 on the site?

Can anyone help me to add this kind of animation in WordPress?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has been the problems you need to overcome? Please try and give a look at this before adding more context to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

they are adding an HTML widget in Elementor with an offscreen canvas created via https://github.com/regl-project/regl. See their code for more reference if you want to dig deeper.

So the correct answer is to code it and inject it into the project. There is probably no built-in function.